# JQuery - using nested each() to update XML string. Original string not updated

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

New user and first question..
I parse an XML string using by nested each()s. I find the node I am looking for and change the property's value, however the original xml string remains unchanged.

XML and JQuery below. Look for the alerts in the code to see where the updating happens. Anyway after all the eachs have played out the original xml string is as it was? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

The XML:

```
<Test TestID="712" UserID="1231230192831039812">
  <Question id="713">
    <AnswerSet id="718" type="5">
      <AnswerSetOption id="740"  IsChecked="Foo" />
      <AnswerSetOption id="741"  IsChecked="Foo" />
      <AnswerSetOption id="742"  IsChecked="Foo" />
    </AnswerSet>
  <AnswerSet id="719" type="5">
    <AnswerSetOption id="740"  IsChecked="Foo" />
    <AnswerSetOption id="741"  IsChecked="Foo" />
    <AnswerSetOption id="742"  IsChecked="Foo" />
  </AnswerSet>
  <AnswerSet id="720" type="5">
    <AnswerSetOption id="740"  IsChecked="Foo" />
    <AnswerSetOption id="741"  IsChecked="Foo" />
    <AnswerSetOption id="742"  IsChecked="Foo" />
  </AnswerSet>
 </Question>
</Test>
```

The Script:

```
    function TrackResponse(QuestionID, AnswerSetID, AnswerSetOptionID, InputType) {

        var xml;

        xml = $('#_uiCheckingAnswersHidden').val();

        $(xml).find('Question').each(function () {

            var xmlQuestionID = $(this).attr('id');

            $(this).find('AnswerSet').each(function () {

                var xmlAnswerSetID = $(this).attr('id');

                $(this).find('AnswerSetOption').each(function () {

                    var xmlAnswerSetOptionID = $(this).attr('ID');
                    var checkedValue = $(this).attr('IsChecked');


                    if (InputType == 'radio') {

                        if (QuestionID == xmlQuestionID && AnswerSetID == xmlAnswerSetID && AnswerSetOptionID == xmlAnswerSetOptionID) {

                            alert('Found it');

                            var oldValue;

                            oldValue = $(this).attr('IsChecked');

                            alert('Old value: ' + oldValue)

                            $(this).attr('IsChecked', 'Bar');

                            var newValue;

                            newValue  = $(this).attr('IsChecked');

                            alert('New value: ' + newValue)

                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).attr('IsChecked', 'pp');
                        }
                    }

                    //Checkbox -- if not found updated Checked Attribute to ''
                    if (InputType == 'check') {

                        var checked = $(this).attr('IsChecked');

                        if (QuestionID == xmlQuestionID && AnswerSetID == xmlAnswerSetID && AnswerSetOptionID == xmlAnswerSetOptionID) {

                            if (checked == 'true') {
                                $(this).attr('IsChecked', 'dd');
                            }
                            else {
                                $(this).attr('IsChecked', '');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        alert(xml);
    }
```

Comment: When you call `$(xml)` you're creating a new jQuery object containing the nodes defined in the `xml` string; the two now have absolutely no connection to one another. If you want to get a new XML string to represent the changed state you'll need to obtain it from that object.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. So I will have to join up all the nodes again and recreate the xml to get the updated value? Is there an easy way to join all the nodes or do I have to create the original xml format with the updated attribute value?

Comment: I'd store a reference to the jQuery object created by calling `$(xml)`, since that will reflect the later changes (assuming you use that variable in place of any `$(xml)` calls in your current code). There are a couple of questions about obtaining an XML string from a jQuery object here on SO, so do a search for one of those.

Comment: How do I store a reference to the jQuery object created by calling $(xml) as you say? I will then have a look for how to get the XML string from the object.

Comment: Just do: `var xmlObject = $(xml);`. Then `xmlObject` will reference the jQuery object that's returned by calling `$(xml)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do all the aforementioned and access the original DOM element by reference, or you can just replace or append the XML content over the current content with .html(xml) or something.